# Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE fails starting due to Hystrix and gradle upgrade?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

we recently updated Spring boot from 1.3.7.RELEASE to Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE 
and also we are upgrading java7 to Java11(Open amazon-corretto-11.jdk) and also we upgraded the gradle distribution version from Gradle 2.10 to Gradle 5.3 as well.

**Note:** we have dependancy for hystrix as well , 
and when we specify the Hystrix 
version as 1.1.7.RELEASE. 
Code compiles fine but failed to start the application with below error:

compile ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:1.1.7.RELEASE")
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard:1.1.7.RELEASE"

**Error:** o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)**

**Can anyone help us on this issue? prompt response will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

spring-cloud-starter-hystrix 1.1.7 is built for Spring Boot 1, it's [from 2016](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix). If you upgrade Spring Boot, you need to upgrade **all** the related dependencies too.

I highly suggest you don't upgrade to a really old version of Spring Boot 2.1, upgrade directly to Spring Boot 2.1.12.RELEASE so you have all the necessary bug and CVE fixes. And pick a hystrix dependency which belongs to Spring Boot 2.1.x, which likely is [spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix 2.1.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix/2.1.5.RELEASE).